# GC collecting 'pinned' arrays on call to bindings in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, accelerate-framework

Afternoon,

I've had the same Xamarin.iOS bindings to native code for roughly 3 years working flawlessly but lately i've noticed a crash behaviour that might have been there since the beginning. I deal with bindings of large (and also small) arrays like images and so on.

**The issue**: It seems like the GC is collecting some of the structures while the unmanaged calls to native are operating. I am 'pinning' the data involved and method binding calls with unsafe fixed statements.

```
fixed (double* px = _px)
{
    fixed (double* py = _py)
    {
        fixed (double* param = parameters)
        {
            fixed (int* distMap = _distMap)
            {
                IntPtr dataPxPtr = new IntPtr((void*)px);
                IntPtr dataPyPtr = new IntPtr((void*)py);
                IntPtr parametersPtr = new IntPtr((void*)param);
                IntPtr distMapPtr = new IntPtr((void*)distMap);
                _bindings.Initiate(dataPxPtr, dataPyPtr, parametersPtr, distMapPtr, 1E-4, Size.Width);
                _bindings.Iterate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically the nested fixed statement should pin the memory addresses whilst the binding methods run. But that doesn't seem to be the case...

**Xamarin Side Stacktrace**

```
Warning (239) / iOSApp: critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
Warning (239) / iOSApp: critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ...Messaging.void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr) <0x00007>
Warning (239) / iOSApp: critical:   at ...Bindings.Iterate () <0x00047>
```

**XCode Stacktrace**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001088fc018
Triggered by Thread:  4

Thread 4 name:  tid_681f
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182cac11c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182d78ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182c1ddc8 abort + 140
3   iOSApp                          0x0000000100ed26cc mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2462)
4   iOSApp                          0x0000000100eddccc mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini-runtime.c:2906)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000182d7194c _sigtramp + 68
6   iOSApp                          0x00000001000ed77c lmdif_ (lmdif_.c:468)
7   iOSApp                          0x00000001000f1e44 lmdif1_ (lmdif1_.c:153)
8   iOSApp                          0x00000001000ec3c8 -[Bindings iterate] (Bindings.m:403)
9   iOSApp                          0x0000000101bf1698 wrapper_managed_to_native_Bindings_Messaging_void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr (/<unknown>:1)
10  iOSApp                          0x0000000101bf0428 Bindings_Iterate (/<unknown>:1)
```

I've tried, with no success:

- Attempting to make deep copies in C# to IntPtr and pass them to bindings
- Attempting to make deep copies in obj-c as soon as they are passed to the bindings
- Attempting pinning of arrays in C# managed side (GCHandle) and use them to pass to the bings (gchandle.free() after obv)
- others i cant remember...

Any help would be appreciated as i'm going nuts.

Thanks,

Antonio